How can I change the app name in Flutter for Android and iOS?
I have a Flutter project, and I want to change the app name that appears on the home screen for both Android and iOS platforms.
My questions are:

What are the exact steps to change the app name in Flutter for Android?
What are the exact steps to change the app name for iOS?
Do I need to run any additional commands or clear caches after making these changes?

I would appreciate any detailed instructions or references.

For Android platform, locate AndroidManifest.xml in folder android/app/src/main of your project library. The app's display name is set here:
<application android:label="your-app-name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

For iOS you need to edit the Info.plist file in folder ios/Runner in your  project directory and look for these:
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>your-app-name</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>your-app-name</string>

You need to build the app for these changes to take effect. If the display name is not changed, try to run flutter clean and flutter pub get and build again.
